(the letter) k is the same as f for some reason
input is a string and well...when input[0] is 'k', its apparently the same as 'f'? like clearly it should be false and not output "f detected" right? k seems to have a value of 107 and f seems to have a value of 102 so even when read as ints, it doesnt seem like it should be possible for them to be equal



Watch your semicolons ;.

where is this getint function coming from ?. Read the posting guidelines - posting images is frowned upon, copy/paste is all that's needed. Post your code - not just some random snippet so we can see really whats going on. if you believe 'f' === 'k' then there's other issues that need to be dealt with.

For future reference, read Why should I not post images of code/data/errors when asking a question?

Like what @Dúthomhas commented, you have a semicolon after your if statement.
if (input[0] == 'f');

remove it and your code should work.
if (input[0] == 'f')

The semicolon effectively ends the if statement, so the block that follows is always executed, regardless of the condition.
